# How should I connect a Honeywell T2 with no C or Y wire?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Hello everyone I am a DIY type of guy but I’ve possibly bit off more than I can chew. Our older LUX thermostat was not cooling the house, so I was told to replace it. I did. Well, now the ac does not blow cool air at all.

I’ve upgraded from the Lux to a T2 from Honeywell. I have no c wire and I now have a blue wire but no y. I’m so confused. Please help me out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm please about the two brown cables to the right of your photo: the upper one goes to the thermostat, and the lower on I believe goes to the transformer.  Is that right?  Or if not, what is that lower cable?  If I have it right the solution I believe is simple.

Comment: Okay sooo I’m not sure to be completely honest but what’s on my furnace isn’t the same thing that’s on the actual thermostat I’m not sure what the transformer is I have included the diagram on the back of the panel I hope that can be some help

Comment: Does the thermostat have a battery?  If not, the disconnected C terminal will prevent it from working, and the fix should be easy.  I'll write an answer on that basis.

Comment: I don't understand the part about no Y wire.  The Y terminal and yellow wire are clearly visible.  What do you mean by no Y wire?

Comment: @jay613, the brown cable that has a red and white wire is the cable that goes outside to control the compressor.

Comment: What's the actual thermostat model?   I've seen the T1, T4, 5, 6 , I have a T5, ... and just assumed there was a T2 but I don't actually see such a thing. https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/support/air/thermostats/product-selector/installation/

Answer (score 2):

I think the Honeywell T2 does not have a battery so the disconnected C wire will prevent it from working.

There is a spare blue wire on the upper brown cable.  Connect it at the furnace to the terminal marked "C", together with the white wire that is already there.    (You can see on the "Y" terminal how two wires can be connected to the same terminal.)

Then, at your thermostat, find the blue wire and connect it to the "C" terminal on the Honeywell baseplate.  All the other wires should be connected to the baseplate in the obvious way (R/W/Y/G).  You can add a picture of that to your question to confirm.

That ought to do the trick.  If I'm wrong about the T2 and it does have a battery, the problem might not be so simple.

Comment: Thanks for responding yes the T2 requires a battery I’m going to upload a pic of thermostat wires inside the wall